# Traversing through list and comparing

Tags: python, list, parsing, traversal

I have two lists: `focalStart` (imported from another function) that is a list of time stamps and `startDate` which is time stamps read from a csv file. The goal of the function is to traverse through `focalStart` and append the index into a new list `start` if the element is greater than or equal to the i *th* element in `startDate` and greater than the i+1 *th* element.

The code I have works but the length of `startDate` is dependent on the csv file and will change. I know that this can be done using a loop but everything besides this that I have tried does not work. All help is appreciated.

```
def startDate():
#session start
startDate = []
start = []
final = []
focalStart = startTime()
with open('focalVarsTable.csv') as file:
    read = csv.reader(file)
    for row in read:
        if row[1] not in startDate:
            startDate.append(row[1])
startDate.pop(0)

for x in focalStart:
    if x >= startDate[0] and x < startDate[1]:
        start.append(startDate[0])
    elif x >= startDate[1] and x < startDate[2]:
        start.append(startDate[1])
    elif x >= startDate[2] and x < startDate[3]:
        start.append(startDate[2])
    elif x >= startDate[3] and x < startDate[4]:
        start.append(startDate[3])
    elif x >= startDate[4]:
        start.append(startDate[4])
```

Comment: How, or are you guaranteed that the length of `startDate` is `len(focalStart) + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for x in focalStart:
    for y in range(len(startDate)):
        if x >= startDate[y] and x < startDate[y+1]:
            start.append(startDate[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer was close, I believe you need len() around the startDate conditional so that you pass indices to range(). Try this:

```
for x in focalStart:
    for y in range(len(startDate)):
        if x >= startDate[y] and x < startDate[y+1]:
            start.append(startDate[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed that the length of `startDate` is one or more than `focalStart`, then it can be done without unnecessarily using nested loops.

```
start = []
for (index, timeStamp) in enumerate(focalStart):
    if(timeStamp >= startDate[index] and timeStamp > startDate[index+1]):
        start.append(index)
```

`enumerate(focalStart)` sets `timeStamp` as an element of `focalStart` while setting `index` as the location of `timeStamp` found in `focalStart`.